# Optimization of matrix determinant calculation

Tags: optimization, c, recursion, matrix

I have this algorithm that calculates the matrix determinant using recursive divide-and conquer-approach:

```
int determ(int a[max][max],int max) {
  int det=0, p, h, k, i, j, temp[max][max];
    //base case omitted
    for(p=0;p<max;p++) {
      h = 0;
      k = 0;
      for(i=1;i<max;i++) {
        for( j=0;j<max;j++) {
          if(j==p) {
            continue;
          }
          temp[h][k] = a[i][j];
          k++;
          if(k==max-1) {
            h++;
            k = 0;
          }
        }
      }
      det=det+a[0][p]*pow(-1,p)*determ(temp,max-1);
    }
    return det;
}
```

I want to optimize the main loop (with a loop unwinding or any strategy that can reduce the execution time).  Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it is not a divide and conquer, it's a combinatorial explosion. The timing complexity

$$T(n) = nT(n-1)$$

evaluates to `n!` - exponential growth. There is no way to heal the code; you have to choose another algorithm.

Comment: could you suggest me any better alternative algorithm?

Comment: Start with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435133/what-is-the-best-matrix-determinant-algorithm

Comment: Seems that using the Cramer rule find determinant is O(n^3) but I don't know if is this strategy valid for all n*n matrix of any size, and I haven't idea how exactly should I implement this algorithm to get O(n^3) complexity code. Could you give me more details?

Comment: Gaussian elimination http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Computing_determinants is a good starting point.

Comment: what do you think about the efficency of the second c method proposed here? thanks http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Matrix_arithmetic

Comment: Sorry for taking that much time to answer. I looked at the rosettacode and frankly I do not like how it is written. I think it is also buggy (in fact, it did fail few tests).